# Can I add SQL statements in Oracle Loader file

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-loader

I suppose to write Oracle Loader file to insert/append the data from csv file.
Now I have a requirement where I have to change column filed of ecery existing record before doing the insert/append. Is it possible to add some PL/SQL statement in the Oracle Loader script file before start of the append?

Comment: if you want to run some plsql code before inserting or updating ... you can use trigger also ..

Comment: I wan to run it only once before starting the appending the new data. Example: if there is 4 rows and going to insert new 5 rows from csv then before append the first row of the csv file, i like to increment a value of existing rows.

Comment: that is also possible in Oracle database. you can use statement level trigger where trigger will be triggered only once for a statement.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.

If you're executing SQL*Loader or using external tables you must be doing it within some calling program though. If you want to perform some action prior to loading then add a step before you load that performs that action.